# Challah Loaves on Shabbat have a minimum size?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shiurim-measurements, challah-shabbat-bread

In [this article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1108296/jewish/Lechem-Mishneh-The-Two-Shabbat-Loaves.htm) regarding the Shabbat Challah loaves, The Shmirat Shabbat KeHilchata (vol. II 55:5) is [quoted as saying](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1108296/jewish/Lechem-Mishneh-The-Two-Shabbat-Loaves.htm#footnote10a1108296):

> The loaves must each be at least the size of an olive

Normally, the size of the food being eaten does not matter when making a preceding blessing (see [here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbosVII-29.pdf), for example). The only requirement is that, in order to make an after-blessing, one must eat the required amount within a set time-period (see [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1108296/jewish/Lechem-Mishneh-The-Two-Shabbat-Loaves.htm#footnoteRef48a1108296), for example)

I don't have access to the Shmirat Shabbat KeHilchata, and I'm looking for sources and an explanation why the loaves used on Shabbat have a minimum size requirement.

Comment: I'm thinking you may want to take a look at the original Hebrew if you can get it. Check Hebrewbooks.

Comment: @SethJ: I haven't found Shmirat Shabat Kehilchata anywhere online yet, and I have no access to the original sefer.

Comment: @SethJ Menachem, I have transcribed the english text in my answer.

Comment: -1; IMHO, I think that if a *kezayit* is not enough to induce *oneg shabbat*, a person has not fulfilled their obligation of a seudah.

Comment: @AdamMosheh: Thanks for explaining your reason for downvoting. However, I'm not sure I understand it. You seem to be addressing something different to my question. Regardless of whether the person is satisfied with a kezayit, the Sh"Sh"K is saying that the challah rolls used when making the Hamotzie blessing should be at least a Kezayit. I'm asking why. Your response seems to be that it is not a good question because a person must eat until he is satisfied on Shabbat. Even if that is the case, why couldn't he have a bunch of small rolls until he is satiated?

Answer (score 5):

The minimum shiur to fulfill the mitzva of eating a seuda on Shabbos is a kezayis [O Ch 271 MB [35]](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=95).

That means that you must have one loaf of at least a kezayit. The second loaf comes for the (separate) obligation of lechem mishneh.

**ADDITION**:
The sources quoted by the Shmiras Shabbos Kehilchoso are:

1. [Kaf Hachaim 274 sk 8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14421&pgnum=116) says that in  [בית מנוחה או׳ י״ב](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19666&pgnum=99)‏ it says that loaves less than a kezayis are alright for Lechem Mishneh but the [Kaf Hachaim (of R' Chaim Pelaji) 36:44](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7882&pgnum=576) does not allow it even if you have 12 loaves like that. He also quotes the  [ד) ,פתה״ד) (Petach HaDvir)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7976&st=&pgnum=189)  who agrees with the Kaf Hachaim.
2. [Rivevos Efraim 1 (204)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&st=&pgnum=161). He quotes as follows:

   - [Sdei Chemed (Ma'arechet Lamed, Klal 27)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14154&pgnum=281) brings:

     - Chikrei Lev – doubtful
     - Beis Menucha  - ok
     - Pesach HaDvir – is machmir but it does work bedieved
   - Rabbi Y Bernstein (?) – one should be concerned for those who who do not allow it; even if he could make up the kezayis with other pieces of bread
   - Rav Ch Kanievsky wrote to him that 
     “מסתבר שצריך כזית”. He recommends studying שאלי ציון part 1 (9) (not on Hebrewbooks.com).

CYLOR!

Comment: I don't follow. Couldn't you have two loaves each a half zayit, and eat both of them?

Comment: As @DoubleAA pointed out, that is just how much you have to eat. That applies during the week as well. It doesn't say that the loaves you're making a blessing on have to have a minimum size, just that you have to eat a minimum amount ---- Also, look in Shaar HaTzion 43, where he says that it looks like one has to eat the volume of an egg to fulfill the mitzva of seudat shabbat.

Comment: I had found the Petach Devir from the Kaf HaChaim http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7976&st=&pgnum=187 but I wasn't able to understand his argument

Comment: Avrohom Yitzchok, thanks for the additional information and sources!

Comment: @DoubleAA From what I could see the Petach Dvir that you quoted is concerned with joining two “half breads” when he does not have a whole loaf. I suggest the reference is to [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7976&st=&pgnum=189) where he says that it is poshut that you cannot use bread less than a kezayit because (my translation) it is “not bread as far as the brocho of hamotzi is concerned and as far as doing your duty of eating matzo on Pesach”. (!) I haven’t been able to decipher the rest now.

Comment: Hmm odd. We do say a hamotzi on less than a kezayit in general IIUC

Comment: The Sha'alei Tzion is probably the Sha'alot U'Teshuvot by http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%91

Comment: @DoubleAA: That's exactly what the Beit Menucha says.

Comment: I was told by Rabbi Reuven Lauffer of Ohr Somayach that *each* loaf must be a minimum of 24 grams, but he didn't bring sources.  That's smaller than [some opinions on the size of a kezayit](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Reference_of_Measurements_in_Halacha); I don't know if he holds to a smaller kezayit or if something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Someone told me that his father taught him that in order to wash, the bread must be at least the size of an egg. I asked him for sources but he didn't have any, so neither do I.

But maybe someone here has heard this too.

From the English, volume 3 (not 2):

> One should make a point of taking, for lechem mishneh, loaves which are each at least a ka-zayith in size.

Note the change from "must" to "make a point of".

Comment: This is really a separate question, rather than an answer to this one. That being said, one must always wash, but in order to make a blessing on the washing, one must eat at least 2 olive-size worth of bread (i.e. the size of an egg) See "Seder Netilat Yadayim Le'Seuda" in the Shulchan Aruch HaRav, Halacha 18:  http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&pgnum=664 -- see here for an explanation (Orach Chaim 158:2) http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/13/158/2.htm

Comment: @Menachem Thanks! Sorry I couldn't answer your question, but I did get an answer to mine :) (I've always wondered why.)

Comment: Is it still 55:5 in volume three, or is it somewhere else? Also, is there any more information given, such as sources or reasons?

Comment: @Menachem Yes, still 55:5, there are no sources (at all), and I've transcribed it exactly. It continues with a discussion of making sure there is enough for everyone.

Comment: @Menachem re "one must always wash, but in order to make a blessing on the washing, one must eat at least 2 olive-size worth of bread (i.e. the size of an egg)": I *think* this is a _machlokes haacharonim_. IIRC _MB_ rules as you said but others hold one need not wash (or bless) except for a olive's size or two.

Comment: (Not to mention the machloket rishonim about how many olives make up an egg. Why not just say egg instead of 2 olives?)

Comment: @DoubleAA: I should have. In fact, that's what is says in the Shulchan Aruch I linked to.

Comment: @msh210: The second Shulchan Aruch HaRav I linked to above (158:2) says that the reason we wash without a blessing is because some say that there is no need to wash if one is eating less than an egg size piece. See a discussion on this in the Ketzos Hashulchan, Badei HaShulchan 36:4, who brings the Beit Yosef who quotes the Rokeach that one should wash without a blessing, and explains why the Shulchan Aruch HaRav gives a different reason than the Beit Yosef. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7721&pgnum=34 -- can you point out any Acharonim who say one need not wash at all?

Comment: @Menachem Are you looking for achronim that say no need to wash at all on less than a zayit or less than a beitza?

Comment: @DoubleAA: msh210 wrote: _IIRC MB rules as you said but others hold one need not wash (or bless) except for a olive's size or two._ I'm looking for acharonim  who say that you do not need to wash at all. (i.e. after the Beit Yosef brought the Rokeach and said that one should wash without a blessing, is there anyone who disagrees and says you do not need to was at all.)

Comment: @Menachem The Mishna Berura quotes the Bach, Taz, Gra, Birkei Yosef, and Rashbatz who hold that no washing at all is necessary on less than an olive. I haven't checked those inside. The Aruch Hashulchan notes that the common practice is not to wash on less than an olive in accordance with the above cited opinions.